# How do I detect a collision with a color?

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

How do I detect a collision with my map? I want to detect a collision with my map and my car. scanning for the colors.

on my undermap: the track is gray, the grass is white and the walls are yellow.

on my uppermap: the track is more realistic, it is what they see.

I tried http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/theroadnottaken/theroadnottaken.shtml but when I was at collisions, the code won't work. A lot of that is not working in XNA 4.0 but it is exactly what I could use.

```
//This method checks to see if the Sprite is going to move into an area that does
//not contain all Gray pixels. If the move amount would cause a movement into a non-gray
//pixel, then a collision has occurred.
private bool CollisionOccurred(int aMove)
{

    //Calculate the Position of the Car and create the collision Texture. This texture will contain
    //all of the pixels that are directly underneath the sprite currently on the Track image.
    float aXPosition = (float)(-mCarWidth / 2 + mCarPosition.X + aMove * Math.Cos(mCarRotation));
    float aYPosition = (float)(-mCarHeight / 2 + mCarPosition.Y + aMove * Math.Sin(mCarRotation));
    Texture2D aCollisionCheck = CreateCollisionTexture(aXPosition, aYPosition);

    //Use GetData to fill in an array with all of the Colors of the Pixels in the area of the Collision Texture
    int aPixels = mCarWidth * mCarHeight;
    Color[] myColors = new Color[aPixels];
    aCollisionCheck.GetData<Color>(0, new Rectangle((int)(aCollisionCheck.Width / 2 - mCarWidth / 2), (int)(aCollisionCheck.Height / 2 - mCarHeight / 2), mCarWidth, mCarHeight), myColors, 0, aPixels);

    //Cycle through all of the colors in the Array and see if any of them
    //are not Gray. If one of them isn't Gray, then the Car is heading off the road
    //and a Collision has occurred
    bool aCollision = false;
    foreach (Color aColor in myColors)
    {
        //If one of the pixels in that area is not Gray, then the sprite is moving
        //off the allowed movement area
        if (aColor != Color.Gray)
        {
            aCollision = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return aCollision;
}
```

Part 2

```
//Create the Collision Texture that contains the rotated Track image for determing
//the pixels beneath the Car srite.
private Texture2D CreateCollisionTexture(float theXPosition, float theYPosition)
{
    //Grab a square of the Track image that is around the Car
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, mTrackRender);
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target, Color.Red, 0, 0);

    mSpriteBatch.Begin();
    mSpriteBatch.Draw(mTrack, new Rectangle(0, 0, mCarWidth + 100, mCarHeight + 100), 
        new Rectangle((int)(theXPosition - 50), 
        (int)(theYPosition - 50), mCarWidth + 100, mCarHeight + 100), Color.White);
    mSpriteBatch.End();

    graphics.GraphicsDevice.ResolveRenderTarget(0);
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, null);

    Texture2D aPicture = mTrackRender.GetTexture();

    //Rotate the snapshot of the area Around the car sprite and return that 
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, mTrackRenderRotated);
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target, Color.Red, 0, 0);

    mSpriteBatch.Begin();
    mSpriteBatch.Draw(aPicture, new Rectangle((int)(aPicture.Width / 2), (int)(aPicture.Height / 2), 
        aPicture.Width, aPicture.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, aPicture.Width, aPicture.Width), 
        Color.White, -mCarRotation, new Vector2((int)(aPicture.Width / 2), (int)(aPicture.Height / 2)), SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    mSpriteBatch.End();

    graphics.GraphicsDevice.ResolveRenderTarget(0);
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, null);

    return mTrackRenderRotated.GetTexture();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at any of the ms game tutorials? Collision is usually done by putting a rectangle around your object and seeing if it intersects with another object (which has a rectangle around it too).

Comment: You're looking for `per-pixel collision detection`.

Comment: do not use pixel collision, it's FPS and CPU killer. use rectangle, circle, polygon collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do not recomend pixel collision, as it's uncecessary CPU and FPS killer.
here are some collsions that could help you. but if you really need pixel collision, first check rectange or any other collision detection and then if intersect then use pixel collsion to be preciesly... but I don't recomend that, especially in fast games.

here are some collision function that could help you

POLYGON

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15573/2D-Polygon-Collision-Detection

CIRCLE:

```
int circlesColliding(int x1,int y1,int radius1,int x2,int y2,int radius2)
{
    //compare the distance to combined radii
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;
    int radii = radius1 + radius2;
    if ( ( dx * dx )  + ( dy * dy ) < radii * radii ) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

CIRCLE TO RECTANGLE

```
bool intersects(CircleType circle, RectType rect)
{
    circleDistance.x = abs(circle.x - rect.x);
    circleDistance.y = abs(circle.y - rect.y);

    if (circleDistance.x > (rect.width/2 + circle.r)) { return false; }
    if (circleDistance.y > (rect.height/2 + circle.r)) { return false; }

    if (circleDistance.x <= (rect.width/2)) { return true; } 
    if (circleDistance.y <= (rect.height/2)) { return true; }

    cornerDistance_sq = (circleDistance.x - rect.width/2)^2 +
                         (circleDistance.y - rect.height/2)^2;

    return (cornerDistance_sq <= (circle.r^2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to solve your particular case, but I'm just going to recommend [Riemers](http://www.riemers.net/eng/tutorials.php)

I'm sure one of his tutorial has colour detecting, I think its his 2d tank game.

Mona